# ArcGIS 10 - disappearing rasters?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.0

From time to time it happens to me that rasters disappear at certain zoom level in ArcMap, or only some parts of the raster (strips) show up. I'm working on WinXP, ArcGIS / ArcView 10, Sp2, rasters are jpg files, both with and without pyramids. Anyone facing a similar behaviour? Any tips what is the reason and solution for this? It's really annoying.

Comment: Look trough the answers, I'am pretty sure that there have been some similar questions. As far, as I remember there has been issue with statistics and mosaics, when migrated from 9.x to 10. Also update your Arc to SP3.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't ask the question here if I'd have found the answer somewhere else ;) But you're right: the question has been asked before (e.g. http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/687-Beta-10-Disappearing-raster-image), but the issue was not solved. Meanwhile I've upgraded to SP3 and the problem still persists. SP3 is supposed to address the following bug: "NIM061731 - Some parts of the TIFF image disappears when zoomed in close", but apparently it doesn't help with JPGs.

Comment: May be something here may help http://forumsstg.arcgis.com/threads/12669-Raster-disappears-on-zoom-in-ArcGIS-10 , not sure though worth to check.

Comment: @jan_b Have you managed to sort out this issue? I'm getting similar problem with large terrain model raster :/

Comment: @radek I didn't come up with a universal solution. In some cases recreating pyramids helped, in others I tried converting raster to different formats. Still, weird things happen to rasters, even in recent versions of ArcGIS...

Comment: @jan_b Thanks for information. Quite unusual behaviour for such an expensive piece of software I'd say :/ I tried recalculating pyramids and statistics - to no avail. May I ask to which format you converted as a remedy?

Comment: @radek Usually I try with MrSID and/or file geodatabase rasters. But there is hardly any consistence in this behaviour.

Comment: Is there a real solution/hack to this problem in the meantime ? I'm working on arcmap 10.4. Very time consuming bug for inspection.
Would be great to hear a solution, lots of people talking about it but no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same stripe-problem I found out that only **progressive JPG** produce these stripes.
I exported the image as **non-progressive JPG** and the stripes where gone. Playing around I found out the visible stripe occurs where you zoom in first. Areas above and under are not visible if you zoom in beyond a certain zoom level.

Recalculating or abandoning the pyramids made no difference.

(ArcGIS 10.2.2 with a JPG, 3000x2500 pixel, exported from PDF, tested with GIMP and Irfan)

To convert progressive to non-progressive JPG lossless with Irfan View you can follow [this tutorial](http://kb.tourwriter.com/converting-jpeg-images-using-irfanview).